# GameSalad like tools for PC

Tags: game-engine, gamekit

Anyone knows of a tool like GameSalad for PC in which you don't have to write scripts or anything but just use the existing behaviors and events to create custom game logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GameMaker](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker) is one such tool.

There is also [The 3d Gamemaker](http://www.thegamecreators.com/?m=view_product&id=2126), by the same people who make other rapid-game-development tools like DarkBasic.

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer. GM is limited to only PC, right?
What I want is something that supports multiplatform like gamesalad.
It'd be something like a opengl base game making tool, so that it can compile to multi platforms, including ogl es mobile.

I don't think there is one. or is there?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a cross platform game constructor you might want to try [Flowlab](http://flowlab.io), which runs in a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

Construct from Scirra is a free, open-source, drag and drop, game engine. There is however talk of them making a paid version of Construct in the future.

I've only used Construct once, so I don't know that much about it, but i do know a lot about GameMaker. 
As long as your not trying to do something complicated like a 3D or MMO game, (both of which GameMaker supports, but with major limitarions) I would recommend you use it, especially if your just starting out. GameMaker is one of the easiest if not the easiest programming language to learn. It also teaches good programming skills. As I mentioned before GameMaker uses drag and drop so you can easily transition from the D&D to the progeamming aspect of GameMaker.

As mentioned in the above posts RPG Maker is another popular tool , but it's limited to RPG games, and doesn't allow you to easily transition to an actual programming language. It's also very restrictive in what you can do.

When you feel like getting into some more advanced gaming engines, Blender is a great tool to use for creating 3D games. It can also be used to create 3D modules and has the ability to create animated movies.

I've never used PyGames before, but Python is a easy language to learn, and would probably be the best way to transition from a D&D program to a programming language.

*GameMaker can be extended in functionality with DLLs and Blender can be extended with Python.

So to summarize, GameMaker is a great tool for creating Games. RPG Maker and Construct are other possibilities, but from my view there not as good as GameMaker. when your ready to get out of Drag&Drop gaming engines Blender, PyGames, and GML(Game Maker Language - the advanced part of the GameMaker product) are all great resources.

Answer (score 1):

PlayBits has an interface similar to GameSalad and makes games for Windows Phone 7, using your PC. Here's the link: http://www.playbits.com/?page_id=171

Answer (score 1):

RPG maker [here](http://www.rpgmakerweb.com/) you can find it is a light weight game engine but if you are clever you can make really good apps

Answer (score 1):

In terms of game development for iOS and Mobile development using the Windows platforms you might want to have a look at these two:

http://www.giderosmobile.com

and

http://www.stencyl.com/

Although I haven't, yet, used the Gideros solution, it's targeted specifically for Mobile platform development and has what looks to be a tidy UI with code folding and syntax coloring if you're comfortable with a traditional coding approach.

Stencyl is an interesting product, it sits beyond the capabilities of Gamesalad and uses a blocks metaphor for programming which works well.

Personally, I wouldn't use any tool that has a single platform for output, which is why I stopped using Gamemaker (I'm aware it now has a Macintosh client, but the quality of the application has been terrible and their player isn't much good either.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for [GameSalad for Windows](http://www.scirra.com) you might want to check out our [HTML5 game engine Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com) which functions in a similar way.

It's also got an event based system with no programming required, and there's an extensive free edition available for you to try out as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yoyo Game's  [GameMaker:Studio](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/studio) also.